# How to use thread-local storage with parallelism?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, c++14, threadpool, boost-thread

I'm trying to replace the usage of `std::async` with thread pooling. Currently, I'm trying to use `boost::executors::basic_thread_pool`. The problem, however, is that I have objects, which are not thread-safe to use.

A naive solution would be to make lots of copies, like this:

```
boost::executors::basic_thread_pool thread_pool;

void do_work() {
    const auto computer = slow_creation();

    std::vector<boost::future<result_t>> results;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
    {
        results.push_back(boost::async(thread_pool, computer.deep_copy()));
    }

    // wait to complete
    // use results
}
```

I want it to look something like this:

```
boost::executors::basic_thread_pool thread_pool;

void do_work() {
    const auto computer = slow_creation();

    std::vector<boost::future<result_t>> results;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
    {
        results.push_back(boost::async(thread_pool,
            [] {
                thread_local (but_not_global) copy = computer.deep_copy();
                return copy();
            }
        ));
    }

    // wait to complete
    // use results
}
```

How to do this with Boost or any other library? I would prefer a library-based solution, which has a decent implementation of thread pool.

Comment: How could I not find it! I can just use `std::this_thread::get_id` and get the id regardless of the library used.

Comment: And then I can then have, for example, a map<int, computer_t> with a mutex guarding it.